# Does Winapps not support 22.04?

Tags: command-line, kvm-virtualization, source-packages

I went through this very detailed guide to install a specific VM to eventually install [Winapps](https://github.com/Fmstrat/winapps). Then, I ran into a problem, even after tireless googling for a solution.

[This is the step I'm having trouble with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjUah.png)

[This is my terminal results after trying to complete the step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woPdP.png)

As you can see, it cannot find that package for Winapps even though I followed the instructions correctly (from what I can tell). What am I missing?

At this point, I'm wondering if Winapps works with Ubuntu 22.04 since it was developed in 2020 back during version 20.

The reason I went through this process is to run the latest version of Microsoft Office.

https://github.com/Fmstrat/winapps

Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit: grammar

Comment: It is a good idea to open a GitHub issue and directly ask the developers. Good luck!

Comment: "sudo apt install git clone..." shows that you do not have a gist of what you are trying to do - which is a large security risk. I advise you to read how to install and use `git`. Get yourself acquainted  with the `apt` package manager. (Try to copy&paste your terminal, don't screenshot it)

Comment: @kanehekili Yes, I'm new to Linux. But you can also be more welcoming. Your message would turn off a lot of new users by the way you worded it.

Comment: You are right. Since you successfully installed one package, you can install git the same way and work with it. After you've installed git you can start cloning the project.

Comment: Thank you good sir. I got past the step! Now it wants me to make a config file, which I'm getting close but I'm giving it the wrong directory